# How can I format "MMyy" to "MM/yyyy" in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a date stored in the format of "MMyy" in string. I would like to be a string but convert it o
"MM/yyyy"

I tried the following but it doesn't work

```
public static string formatDate(string inputDate)
{
   DateTime.TryParseExact(inputDate, "MMyyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out 
      DateTime resultDate);
   return resultDate.ToString("MM/yyyy");
}
```

Comment: "but it doesn't work" is not the best practice to report an error. Also, if the date is stored as "MMyy", what do you try to parse it with "MMyyyy"?

Comment: Enjoy dealing with the Y2K problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the format is not correct. You can do the following:

```
public static string formatDate(string inputDate)
{
   DateTime.TryParseExact(inputDate, "MMyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out 
      DateTime resultDate);
   return resultDate.ToString("MM/yyyy");
}
```